# cannot resolve symbol PowerMockRunner

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, powermock

I'm trying to use Powermock for the first time

I use build.gradle and added:

```
dependencies {
...
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.5'
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.5.5'

}
```

now I look at my test class which has:

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Matchers;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;


@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(GeoUtils.class)
```

and get this error:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
             ^
cannot resolve symbol PowerMockRunner
```

how come it resolves `PrepareForTest` and not `PowerMockRunner` ?

Comment: Because you imported PrepareForTest, but you forgot to import PowerMockRunner?

Comment: it doesn't give me any suggestion to `PowerMockRunner ` import as it did with `PrepareForTest`. So I guess it cannot resolve its import anyhow. no?what is it?

Comment: I believe it should be [`org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner`](http://powermock.googlecode.com/svn/docs/powermock-1.5.1/apidocs/org/powermock/modules/junit4/PowerMockRunner.html). If it doesn't accept the import, the dependency must not have been resolved for some reason.

Comment: thanks. please write an answer and I'll vote you

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You need to import `PowerMockRunner` as follows:

```
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
```

Comment: I already have this import. But still i didn't work. I have the jar as well.

Answer (score 42):

PowerMockRunner is part of `powermock-module-junit4.jar`. You need to explicity import this jar

You could specify the dependency for this jar as per your requirement.
Refer to this [link](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.powermock/powermock-module-junit4).

Comment: I already have the import and the jar. But still i didn't work.

Answer (score 26):

You just need to add the gradle dependency

```
testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.4"
```

or if you're use Android Studio version 3+

```
testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.4"
```

Answer (score 13):

I faced this error because I had only the first of the following dependencies added in my pom.xml. Please ensure you add both the following maven dependencies for PowerMock to your pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
<artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
<version>1.6.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
<artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
<version>1.6.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

I also faced with a similar error. Although the jars are already in the classpath, eclipse didn't suggest to import PowerMockRunner class. It was giving  error "Class cannot be resolved to a type". I had to manually add the import "`org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner`".

Answer (score 1):

I came across exactly the same problem just now and both the dependencies were already included in the pom.xml.

For me, it turned out to be Intellij caching issue and invalidating the cache worked for me.

Here are the steps:

IntelliJ -> File Menu -> Invalidate Caches -> Invalidate and Restart

Answer (score 0):

For instrumental tests you have to use androidTestImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.4"

But then I found out, you can´t use PowerMock with instrumental tests:

> PowerMock won't work on Android if you run it on a device since
>   PowerMock is using JVM byte code manipulation. It will work if you run
>   it on a JVM though.

([link to this problem](https://github.com/linkedin/dexmaker/issues/3))